# Cannot Pass event When Using JQuery Click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click

I can't get data from event.data when using the click function below. If I put "event" in the click(smedata, function(event){}) it doesn't fire. If I remove event it does fire. I've done this hundred times in the past but for whatever reason it doesn't work this time. All I can think is that this code is generated during a callback from closing a dialogue window and that is some how interfering. Appreciate any help.

```html
//This is a callback function in a library that gets called after a dialogue 
//window from SharePoint SP.UI.Dialogue gets closed.

OESme.prototype.CloseCallback = function(result, target){
  console.log("callback");

  try{
    var targetArray = target.split(";#");
  }
  catch(e){

  }
  
  //object to be passed to click event
  var smedata = {
    smejson: target,
    id: targetArray[0],
    title: targetArray[1],
    rank: targetArray[2],
    firstname: targetArray[3],
    lastname: targetArray[4]
  }

  var smeID = "smedata" + smedata.id;
  var smeIDJQ = "#" + "smedata" + smedata.id;

  $("#SMEAddedBox").append(
    '<div class="smeitem">' + 
      '<span id="' + smeID + '">x</span>' + smedata.title + 
    '</div>'
  );


   //*******************   
  //When clicking the x it is suppose to remove itself
  //If event is a parameter in the function, it won't fire, if event is removed it fires, but I can't use the object I am trying to pass
  //********************

  $(smeIDJQ).click(smedata, function(event){
      console.log(event.data);
      $(this).parent().remove();

  });
           
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `smedata` to `.click()`? Not sure exactly what you are after but maybe you just need `$(smeIDJQ).click(function(){$(this).parent().remove()});`

Comment: smedata is an object containing data that I need to manipulate in a database before removing the element from the page. Click allows you to pass an object  and a function and then you can access data from the object using event.data. So in my current code I need the value of event.data. Instead nothing happens. The function doesn't get recognized because it has a parameter and never gets called.

Comment: You can use like this for dynamically create div $(document).on('click', '.smeitem', function(){  // here your code });

Comment: So I tried all the suggestions in the comments for this and the in the answer. Nothing working. Using $(document).on('click', '#someid', function(){//code}); worked on one page load. After refreshing without changing code it stopped working. I have a bunch of synchronous and asynchronous functions plus a lot of callbacks firing around this click event. I think the load order is running differently each time depending on how fast the database gets called. Baffled here. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my code was correct. The problem has to do with SharePoint SP.UI.Dialogue.js. All the javascript and jQuery was correct but it was running in the Dialogue window. Basically there are two separate pages running on one page. When the dialogue window closes after the callback the Console in Internet Explorer 11 breaks and doesn't realize that it is suppose to focus on the parent page instead of the child. So it doesn't receive console logs like it should. Closing the Developer tools and reopening (F12) allows the window to refocus the parent properly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're referencing `$(smeIDJQ)` properly. Also, use `.on` instead. Like `$('#smeIDJQ').on('click', function(){};`

Comment: I tried using .on("click") and it didn't work either. smeIDJQ is a variable with the value that reads "#smedata13". It is dynamic and changing depending what item is being pulled from the database so it has to be a dynamically created variable. Done it that way hundreds of times.

Comment: Jquery prefers the use of single quotes. If you can, make sure that you are getting the variable outside the function. Above this block of code   $(smeIDJQ).click(smedata, function(event){
      console.log(event.data);
      $(this).parent().remove();

  });   try using `console.log(smeIDJQ); to make sure it's being called properly. Also, if the variable reads #smedata13, you need to break down the variable into 2 parts. Jquery looks for # identifies inside single quotes. In other words you are saying $(#smedata13) when you need $('#smedata13')

Comment: It would work if you break the # out of your variable and make the variable just smedata13. Then say $('#' + smeIDJQ) as long as smeIDJQ = smedata13, and smedata13 is an id for something, it should work. Double also, do not put double quotes around click. It should be $('#' + smeIDJQ).on('click', function(){*CODE*}; so long as variable smeIDJQ is equal to the name of an html element ID.

Comment: make sure `$(smeIDJQ)` this returns jquery object when run in console first, the `.click` event data syntax is fine.